# When is the product $(1+1)(1+4)…(1+n^2)$ a perfect square?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

This is a modification of [an unanswered problem on the math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614238/integers-n-such-that-ii1i2-cdots-in-is-real-or-pure-imaginary/619597#619597).

When is the product $(1+1)(1+4)…(1+n^2)$ a perfect square?

If $(1+1)(1+4)…(1+n^2)=k^2$ then one possibility is $n=3$, $k=10$.  Could there be other integer solutions for $(n,k)$?

Surely the answer is NO, but I am unable to prove that $n=3$, $k=10$ is the only possibility.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Javier Cilleruelo](https://mathoverflow.net/users/31020/javier) has shown that $n=3$ is the only solution: see http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/cillerue/Papers/squares-sinlogo.pdf .

A couple more comments: apparently Chebyshev already showed that the largest prime factor of $\prod_{j=1}^{n} (1+j^2)$ is bigger than $Cn$ for any constant $C$ provided that $n$ is large.  This would solve the problem for all large $n$ (taking $C=2$ in Chebyshev's work).  The problem of finding the largest prime factor of $\prod_{j=1}^{n} f(j)$ for a polynomial $f$ has been studied by many authors (Erdos, Hooley, Heath-Brown ...); for a first improvement of Chebyshev's work see Erdos's paper http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1952-07.pdf .

Comment: In fact, the first to improve Chebushev's result was Nagell (reference [4] from Cilleruelo paper), who showed that the largest prime factor of the product $\prod f(j)$ is $\ge n\log n.$ Ciruello's proof goes along Nigell's one by making the estimate precise and using computer search for small $n.$

Comment: Why does the fact that the largest prime factor exceeds 2n shows the product is not a perfect square? Presumably it should be pretty obvious but I just don't see it.

Comment: @JohnJiang: If $p$ divides $a^2+1$ and $b^2+1$ then $p$ divides $|a-b|$ or $(a+b)$.  If $p>2n$ and $a$ and $b$ are distinct numbers below $n$, this is impossible.  So a prime larger than $2n$ that divides the product, only divides to exponent $1$.